# Cambiar el formato de fecha de una tabla en SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

mi problema es que tengo una columna de fechas en formato DD/MM/YYYY y necesito transformarlo a YYYY/MM/DD y la verdad es que no encuentro la forma correcta ni el comando o funcion, estoy trabajando en SQLite.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sqlite no tiene un formato de fecha predefinido, las mismas se guardan como numeros o texto. Si qures cambiarlo, inverti el texto y listo.

Comment: Las fechas no se guardan en un formato. El formato es un tema de la capa de presentación, no del almacenamiento.

Comment: @gbianchi Las fechas las tengo como texto, pero si invierto el texto y tengo por ejemplo 13/10/2012 no me quedaria 2102/01/31?

Comment: Eso es un problema de usar lo que no es. Si usaras un tipo de dato hecho para gestionar fechas, cambiar el formato sería simple y no estarías invirtiendo cadenas (que tampoco es porque no hay días 91, 81, 71... para eso que tienes guardado horrible, tienes que separar los `/` y reordenar, no simplemente tratar la fecha como cadena...

Comment: @Alfabravo sqlite no tiene un formato de fecha.

Comment: @gbianchi mala mía. Gracias! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes sacar los substring correspondientes a dia, mes, año y concatenar nuevamente en el formato deseado. Como sqlite no tiene un divisor de cadena, se puede usar [substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr)

```
UPDATE mi_tabla 
SET col_fecha = (substr(col_fecha, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(col_fecha, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(col_fecha, 1, 2)) 
WHERE col_fecha <> ''
```

Lo anterior sobreescribe el propio registro. Si tienes miedo a dañar la data, puedes crear una columna temporal `col_temp`, para guardar los datos convertidos:

```
UPDATE mi_tabla SET col_temp = (substr(col_fecha, 7, 4) || ...
```

Si ves que todo está bien, actualizas `col_fecha` con lo que tiene `col_temp`.

**[*]** Puedes cambiar el separador a `'/'` si lo deseas, pero [acostúmbrate a usar estándares](https://www.google.com/search?q=standard+date+format+iso+8601).